# Oracle jdbc jar unable to down load in maven plugin

Tags: sql, maven, spring-boot

[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

```
    <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
          <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: complete maven POM file is

Comment: It is normal due to oracle licence. Find on web driver and install locally

Answer (score 4):

The latest release of the oracle jdbc driver is available in maven central since a few days (september 2019, announced at Oracle CodeOne), there is no longer a need to install it locally or add obscure other repositories.

See https://medium.com/oracledevs/oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-64fcf724d8b

The coordinates are

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add repository to your build and download:

See on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>HandChina-RDC</id>
            <name>HandChina RDC</name>
            <url>http://nexus.saas.hand-china.com/content/repositories/rdc/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: still i am getting same error    Failed to execute goal on project auth: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.boot:auth:war:2.1.8.RELEASE: Failure to find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: Remove local repository - it is located in  `By default, Maven local repository is defaulted to ${user.home}/.m2/repository folder :

Unix/Mac OS X – ~/.m2/repository
Windows – C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2\repository`

Comment: Or run maven with the `-U` flag to recheck instead of using the cached result

Answer (score 2):

ojdbc7 is absent in the maven central repository

You need to download jar from oracle.com.
Currently it can be downloaded here. Registration is needed.
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-upc-downloads.html

Then import ojdbc7.jar into your local maven repository with the following command
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true`

Alternatively, if your team has it's own remote maven repository, import it there.

edit: fixed mvn command and link